# unable to insert data in sql database with c# even no error accur

Tags: c#, sql

hy I want to insert new record in my database but am unable to do this even code is fully error free, I added following code in my button click event
here is my code

```
SqlConnection con= new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Sample;Integrated Security=true;");
    SqlCommand cmd;
    SqlDataAdapter adapt;

private void btn_Update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string query="insert into users(Name,Password)values('ubaid','ali')";
    cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("Record Updated Successfully");
    con.Close();
}
```

I mean insert query is not updating my database, even when I execute my query it return 2 not 0 which means query applied successfully,

Comment: Do you click the button to trigger it? Does the messagebox pop up saying it was successful?

Comment: What exception is thrown exactly? Are you sure the SQL is right, with those missing spaces? Maybe try `insert into users (Name,Password) values ('ubaid','ali')`

Comment: @itsme86 yes it says even in my dataset it shows new record but when i check database manually it do not show new added data

Comment: How do you know the code is actually executing? Not seeing an error doesn't necessarily mean there isn't an error.

Comment: `ExecuteNonQuery` returns number of records affected. If its 0 then nothing was inserted, you should expect to see the value 1 being returned.

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt no exception thrown .

Comment: What dataset? Maybe you're not showing us enough code.

Comment: As @itsme86 stated just because you insert something in the database does not mean that value is propegated to everything else currently in memory in your application. It is up to the code to sync with the database if you are using ADO.NET directly. As it is the code you have shown works and is without error. There is not much more anyone can do for you without you first editing your question and explaining what you think is going wrong and also including that code.

Comment: @lgor when i execute query it returns me other then 0, means query was working and data insertion done,

Comment: So,the problem must be you are not looking in the right database/table ... :)

Comment: may i ask if your DBMS requires you to handle transactions? if so, try to commit the current transaction after your insert statement...

Comment: Voting down for plaintext password and not using debugger.

Comment: @DarkSquirrel42 i do not understand you, am new in programming

Comment: @Pikoh no if there is problem in table or database then how select query is working fine ?

Comment: I mean,when you are going to de database "manually" to check if the row is inserted...are you sure you are going to the right database/table? Because your code seems just right

Comment: @Pikoh yes yes,

Comment: even i tried Copy if newer or Copy always in Copy to Output Directory but problem is not solved

Comment: what is your DBMS? ... mysql ... postgres ...oracle ... sql server ... sqlite... ? ... it seems that your dbms is presenting you with an environment where you have to declare transactions to be complete ... the database does not persist everything you have done unless you tell it that everything worked as expected and that your changes should be made permanent ... in other words: "Hey DBMS ... Transaction is complete ... commit my changes please..." ...without that, the changes are only inside your session and are lost on connection close...

Comment: when in doubt ... try to send another statement before closing the connection ... try sending "COMMIT" or "COMMIT TRANSACTION" ... and... do not save your passwords in clear text please... baaaaad design...really baaaaad design

Comment: @DarkSquirrel42 am using SQL express server and tried this cmd = new SqlCommand("COMMIT", con);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); before closing my connection but same problem

Comment: please execute this, open a reader and get strings for the four fields: "select @@SERVERNAME, @@SERVICENAME, db_name(), SCHEMA_NAME()"

Comment: @DarkSquirrel42 please please use simple and direct words, am not professional. plz tell me like nebiw what i have to do where todo

Comment: @JamesKing -- he's asking you to copy that text between the quotes and paste it into SQL Server Management Studio or your favorite query editor application then execute the query so it returns the four values from the query, then copy/paste those values here so we can look at them.

Comment: @DarkSquirrel42 i got this

Comment: @@SERVERNAME AS Expr1, @@SERVICENAME AS Expr2, DB_NAME() AS Expr3, SCHEMA_NAME() AS Expr4

Comment: ok, maybe that was unclear... but what you need to do does not fit into a comment... i'll post an answer, even though it's not really an answer...

Answer (score 0):

not really an answer but the steps you need to take to see whats going on, so we can help you are a bit longer...

you will need to execute the following query, once in your sql management studio, and once in your program ... i suspect the result being different in both cases

```
select @@SERVERNAME, @@SERVICENAME, db_name(), SCHEMA_NAME()
```

on the code side please use this:

```
private void btn_Update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//    string query="insert into users(Name,Password)values('ubaid','ali')";
//    cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
//    con.Open();
//    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
//    MessageBox.Show("Record Updated Successfully");
//    con.Close();

    string query="select @@SERVERNAME, @@SERVICENAME, db_name(), SCHEMA_NAME()";
    cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
    con.Open();
    using(var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        rdr.read();
        MessageBox.Show($"{rdr.GetString(0)}, {rdr.GetString(1)}, {rdr.GetString(2)}, {rdr.GetString(3)} ");
    }
    con.Close();
}
```

the result should show the name of the server, its instance name, the name of your DB and of the default schema you are using in both cases

example result for my testmachine would look like this:

srv9, MSSQLSERVER, testdb, dbo

expectation in your case:

you will get 2 different results which means that your sql management studio, where you are trying to check if your code did the right thing, is using a different server, instance, database or schema

with the provided information it will be possible to change the used connectionstring so both your clients work on the same database...